# android <merge /> can be used only with a valid viewgroup root and attachtoroot=true

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to inflate a fragment xml that **does not** have merge anywhere in it. Yet I am being given the error stated in the question.

My fragment class :

```
package com.xxxxx.www.xxxxxx;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class ExcercisePlanFragment extends Fragment
{

    public static ExcercisePlanFragment newInstance()
    {
        ExcercisePlanFragment fragment = new ExcercisePlanFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_excercise_plan, container, false);
    }
}
```

Here is `fragment_excercise_plan.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/dark_bg"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:minWidth="88dp"
            android:background="@color/mediumGray"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="CREATE A PLAN"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="OR" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:minWidth="88dp"
            android:background="@color/mediumGray"
            android:paddingLeft="24dp"
            android:paddingRight="24dp"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:text="CHOOSE A PLAN"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have no idea where `build.gradle` is picking up merge. I have another fragment activity which is working perfectly.

Comment: Someone please help!